# MaterialBetterSpinner FloatingLabel Dynamically or Programmatically

Tags: android, spinner, material-design

I'm working on floatinglabel spinners in one of my applications. I'm able to display the spinners from below xml code properly. But now I need to add **app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"** programmatically.

```
<com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_Type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/type"
    app:met_floatingLabel="highlight" />
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the library you use, I've noticed that `MaterialBetterSpinner` library is using `MaterialEditText` [library](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText) as a dependency. Hence `MaterialBetterSpinner` is extending from `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView` so you can simply set floating label mode programmatically by next way:

```
MaterialBetterSpinner spinner = (MaterialBetterSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_Type);
spinner.setFloatingLabel(2L);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am using following url for MaterialBetterSpinner http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/02/android-material-design-spinner-dropdown-example.html

Comment: But i try to workout on your suggestion.It is giving following error.
Must be one of: 0L, 1L, 2L less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection looks at Android API calls that have been annotated with various support annotations (such as RequiresPermission or UiThread) and flags any calls that are not using the API correctly as specified by the annotations.

Comment: Ok, then you can simply pass `2L` as a parameter (it's equal to `FLOATING_LABEL_HIGHLIGHT` exactly), So you're method call would look like: `spinner.setFloatingLabel(2L);`. FYI: 0L is equal to `FLOATING_LABEL_NONE` and 1L is equal to `FLOATING_LABEL_NORMAL`.

Comment: hm, in which case do you call this method? Maybe you should call `requestLayout()` method or `requestFocus()` after that.

Comment: It is giving compile time error not runtime error..once will resolve that only we can go ahead right??

Answer (score 0):

Its not your fault, just library setup is not working.
To make it work, you will have to <s>copy class `MaterialBetterSpinner` from the library
and copy `drawable/ic_expand_more_black_18dp`
add to gradle: `compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'`</s>

**Update:**
Much cleaner solution in you build.gradle in app folder:

```
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile ('com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext', module: 'library'
}
```

Thank you can use in xml `app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"`

Checked on playground project. Works like a charm.